# EAAccessoryManager showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter crashes on iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, eaaccessory

When I try to display the BluetoothAccessoryPicker second time, app crashes at below line with EXC_BREAKPOINT. It's happening only if Bluetooth is turned off. And it is happening only on iOS 10.

```
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:namePredicate completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error)
     {

}];
```

Steps:

1. First call above function and select "ok" in bluetooth "turn on"
   alert.
2. Now call above method again and app crashed with `EXC_BREAKPOINT`.

**Update :** Also I have submitted the bug report on [apple](https://bugreport.apple.com) and they provided the response to my bug as "Duplicate of 27689885 (Open)"

Thanks!

Comment: I get a crash when bluetooth is not enabled even when I try to display it for the first time on iOS 10.0.1

Comment: Submitted a bug-report and added it as public radar: http://openradar.appspot.com/29155887

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I deal with the issue for a time being:

```swift
import ExternalAccessory
import CoreBluetooth

class EAViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    
    var btManager: CBCentralManager ?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        btManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue.main, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: true])
    }
    
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        pair()
    }
    
    func pair() {
        if btManager.state == .poweredOn {
            EAAccessoryManager.shared()
                .showBluetoothAccessoryPicker(withNameFilter: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

This will display a prompt to enable bluetooth or show a picker if the bluetooth is enabled.